# UIPickerView with Tap Recognizer Fails

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I have a UIView subclass that contains a UIPickerView.  The pickerview has a tap gesture recognizer attached.  The idea is that users should be able to tap the pickerview once a row is selected.  This worked previously, but after making some changes it is no longer working, and I've spent a day on it and am stuck.

The UIView is initialized like this:

```
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self)
{
    [Utility NSLogRect:frame caption:@"FRAME="];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.delegate = del;
    backgroundColor = color;
    videoList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self initializeView];
    [self displayPicker];
}
return self;


- (void) initializeView
{
    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,self.frame.size.width,self.frame.size.height)];
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    pickerView.alpha = 1.0f;
    UITapGestureRecognizer* gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pickerViewTapGestureRecognized:)];
    gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [pickerView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    [self addSubview:pickerView];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:pickerView];
}
```

The picker displays the rows and scrolls correctly.  However, the tap gesture does not call its action.  Suggestions?

Comment: Reason for the `UITapGestureRecognizer` ?

Comment: So user can tap the pickerview to indicate they want to accept the selection.

Comment: Answer of @ZDidier in this [link][1] is useful for me.Try it!

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22319427/ios-7-1-uitapgesture-not-working-with-uipickerview

Comment: Answer of @ZDidier in this [link][1] is useful for me.Try it!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22319427/ios-7-1-uitapgesture-not-working-with-uipickerview

Comment: Answer of @ZDidier in this [link][1] is useful for me.Try it!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22319427/ios-7-1-uitapgesture-not-working-with-uipickerview

Answer (score 1):

Is your UIView userInteractionEnabled?

You might wanna look at this , [Dismissing UIPickerView on tapping background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906612/dismissing-uipickerview-on-tapping-background?rq=1)

Comment: userInteractionEnabled didn't help the problem.  After reading the link you posted I thought there might be something useful in there, tried a couple of things that came out of it but it didn't go anywhere.  Thx.

Comment: Unfortunately, userInteractionEnabled wasn't the problem. Looking at other alternatives.

Comment: Then , try to remove the UIpickerView ; just add the Tapgesture on the UIView and fire a method to NSLog; See if then the Gesture is working